# Where is the error in this JSON file?

Tags: php, json

i have this code that load a json file:

```
$string = file_get_contents("prova.json");
//var_dump($string);
$obj=json_decode($string);
var_dump($obj); // i test the content 
foreach($obj->data->users as $user){
        echo $user->username;
}
```

in here the file:

http://goldenmedia.it/sincronizzazione/prova.json

Unfoirtunatly ( i did a var_dump() ) the result is NULL can you see where is the problem ? Apparently the file is well formatted i tested it in here:

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://goldenmedia.it/sincronizzazione/prova.json

Please help me finding the mistake !
Thnaks

Comment: Is $string === FALSE ? This will tell you if getting the contents of the file succeeded or not.

Comment: jsonlint is your friend. And json doesn't accept the last comma :)

Answer (score 5):

You can check your JSON for errors with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). It indicates an error in line 45, where it says:

```
  "punti": "0"
 },            ⇠
]
```

The marked line should not contain a comma. If you are unsure about the precise syntax of JSON, the short diagrams at http://json.org explain it pretty good.